# How to Start the timer in the reminder app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, timer

[image]

I am working on the reminder app I need to start the timer so that after the timer gets over it reminds me the events set by me.

In the image I have encircle the timer.

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval=TimeSpan.


    private int Time;
    DispatcherTimer timer;
    private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Time > 0)
        {
            Time--;
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            Debug.WriteLine("  " + Time + "  \n");
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Time = ((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as PersonalModel).RemainingHours;
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((sender as FrameworkElement)
    }
```

Comment: And what have your tried sofar? Could you supply us with the code you've already written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202965%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) tutorial for how you can set reminders and alert alarms in windows phone 8

and here is the code for setting the reminder in windows phone 8.

```
Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
reminder.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
reminder.BeginTime = beginTime; // it is the time when remider will start reminding(e.g remind me after 8 days and 2 AM hours you will set it DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(8).AddHours(2)
reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

// Register the reminder with the system.
ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```